# Node.js console.log not working

Tags: node.js

Simplest possible code in hello.js

```
(function() {
    console.log("Hello World!");
});
```

Running it with :
$node hello.js

There is NO output. If I remove the enclosing function, works properly. But I do want to use the closure. Any ideas?

Node version 0.10.30. Ubuntu 12.04 x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You,re not running your function.

You should add function call:

```
(function() {
  console.log("Hello World!");
}).call();
```

or simply

```
(function() {
  console.log("Hello World!");
})();
```

Comment: That is indeed right! Javascript keeps confounding me :-(

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function for it to work.

```
(function() {
    console.log("Hello World!");
})();
```

Note the added parentheses that call the function after it's been defined.

Answer (score 1):

You are just defining your function, without calling it. You should adapt your script as follows:

```
console.log("Hello World!");
```

**OR** add [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) your function:

```
 (function() {
     console.log("Hello World!");
 }).call();
```

**OR**:

```
 (function() {
     console.log("Hello World!");
 })();
```

A good resource online to try various scripts is [this](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_nodejs_online.php)